# java предельное значение переменной

Tags: java

Обнаружил не понятное мне явление,
мы имеем переменную типа byte,
инициализируем её как -125 и отнимаем по 1 значению в цикле,
и почему-то -128 - 1 = 127.
Ну понятно что мы достигли предела переменной,
но почему когда мы пытаемся перешагнуть через предел то оказываемся у другого его конца.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte a = -125;

        while(a != 125) {
            a--;
            System.out.println(a);
        }
        System.out.println("END");
    }
}
```

Прошу прояснить причину этого.

Comment: Потому что [дополнительный код](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4). `-128 = 0b10000000`, вычитаем единицу, получаем `0b01111111 = 127`

Answer (score 0):

-128 это `1000 0000`. Отнимаем 1 получается `0111 1111`, т.е. 127.

Comment: Действительно. Спасибо за разъяснение.

Answer (score 0):

если по простому, то воспринимай значение переменных как отрезок от -128 до 127
и когда ты доходишь до края, перескакиваешь в противоположный конец.
это как в забагованной игре провалиться в текстуры или пройти через стену.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в классе math есть методы, которые выбрасывают исключение, если было переполнение переменной
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

поэтому надо знать примерную вместимость переменных байт +-127 , инт +-2.147 миллионов и тд